Abstract symbols in an artistic grid… with a secret meaning
The image depicts a grid of artistic, abstract symbols — the goal is to figure out the secret meaning. The correct answer to this puzzle could be written in approximately 3 to 6 words.


I would venture the answer to be:

 Pride and Prejudice


 The text is a straightforward mono-alphabetic cipher for the opening of the novel: "it is a truth universally acknowledged that a single man in possession of a good fortune must be in want of a wife"


Did you solve this by hand or did you put it into some suitable software?

I used quipquip, but I think I could have done it by hand quicker if my printer wasn't broken. Beginning with "it is" usually makes things pretty easy.
